# We forgot to branch, how do we proceed?

Tags: git, github

So we have 4 developers, let's call them dev1, dev2, dev3, and dev4.

We created a github account, dev1 pushed the code to github, all other devs pulled from github and started working on different hotfixes and improvements.

We did not use branching, so we are all using the master branch.

Then we discovered branching and realize that we should probably branch, for making it easier to merge stuff.

Now if we want to use branching from now on, what's the best course of action? Here is what I'm thinking.

1. Create branches on local copy of every developer
2. Commit and push the code
3. There will be 4 branches for each developer
4. Merge them somehow

Will this work? What I'm worried about right now is that since all developers have done some work and changed their local copies, if they start a new branch, their master branch is already different than the master branch on github.

How do we proceed with minimal effort?

Comment: What are going to be the purposes of you branches? Are your developers working towards different goals/releases?

Comment: yes they are working towards different goals they are working on different components of the same system, the purpose in my understanding will be to make it easier to understand what file comes from which branch. Easier to manage and merge

Comment: Take a look at [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). When I first read it, I could see that there was something there, though I confess I hardly understood any of it. ;-) But now, after a little more git experience, it like a pretty good idea. Maybe someday I'll actually use it. ;-) #doctorhealthyself

Comment: OK, what do you mean by different goals? If it's the same system, are the end products of the different "branches" going to be managed and released separately?

Comment: @CharlesBailey, it's one big project, every developer will be assigned things to work on, their changes will be released continuesly as one system. Say it's like facebook, or stackoverflow or a linux distribution, they have one end product but teams of developers work on them.

Comment: @DavidWeinraub, interesting article, will read before bed tonight.

Comment: You are already using branches. It is impossible to not use branches in Git. Your personal `master` branch is a unique and separate branch from the servers `master` branch. It just happens that git let's your write shorter commands when syncing branches of the same name.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to create additional branches if all your developers are working on the same release of one system.

The simplest workflow is for your developers to commit their work in their local clones, merge in any changes from the shared repository, test the result of this merge and push back to the shared master.

You might consider branching if you were maintaining a released version and working on a future release at the same time or if you had a longer term refactoring or feature under development that you wanted to shield from the master branch for stability reasons.

Otherwise, there is no need to make branches for branches' sake. You would only be making extra management and maintenance work for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

A developer's personal `master` branch being different from the upstream master is not a problem. The developers should all create branches from their own master, then never touch their personal master branches again (maybe even delete them).

Comment: So every time they need to work on something new they create a branch, push that, and someone will merge it into the master branch? And then they pull (update) their master branch so that they have the latest merged stable code?

Comment: @user893730: yes. Or they merge it into master themselves, depending on whether you want code review to happen before merges.